# Tagging based on answers?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Id just want a clarification. Is the tagging supposed to reflect the question, only? Or the thread?

Suppose thequestion is asking for software but all answers are about illustrator. And these answers are accepted. Can one then tag illustrator? Or does it become too leading to answerers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm okay with "retroactive tagging" based on the answers. Sometimes a question is not very well formed and the accepted answer is quite different than what you might expect based on the tags.

The number one purpose of tags is to increase searchability. If you think adding a relevant tag based on the answers would help others find the question, I say go for it.

Comment: So, ones question should not rely on tags for info... if you ask photoshop it needs to be in body text not just tag hint. Well then time to spread some illustrator scripting tags ;)

Comment: I approve this message =)

Comment: I was wondering the same yesterday. So for example, with regards to your answer, would you consider it ok to add an ethics tag to a question about removing watermarks?